# How do i display my js variable multiple times on a page

Tags: javascript

I'm collected a variable from the user, a person name, and storing that in a variable. When I hit next, I want to display the name on several different locations, including a dropdown list. I can get it to display the name outside the dropdown list, but only once.

Here is my html:

Collecting the info

`<label>Student Name</label>
 <input type="text" name="Student Name" id="kidNameInput">`

My Next button

`<input type="button" value="Next" class="button" onclick="nextForm()"></input>`

Displaying the info

```
<label>What did the student do well?</label>
 <div class="custom-select">
   <select name="did-well">
        <option value="0"><span class="kid-name"></span> did a great job at…</option>
        <option value="1"><span class="kid-name"></span> did this…</option>
        <option value="2"><span class="kid-name"></span> did something else…</option>
        <option value="3"><span class="kid-name"></span> was good…</option>
    </select>
```

Here is my javascript:

```
function nextForm() {
    var nameInput = document.getElementById("kidNameInput").value;
    document.getElementsByClassName("kid-name")[0].innerText = nameInput;

}
```

I don't know if it helps. but between forms, all I am doing is hiding them. not sure if I need to have them on a seperate html pages or not.

Comment: Re your deleted question: No there's nothing else to include, this is completely basic functionality. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/nqvjggtr/ or with `size` so you can see all the options: https://jsfiddle.net/nqvjggtr/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're only displaying the variable on index 0 (this first index).

When you perform getElementsByClassName it returns an array like object.

So in your code where you have :

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("kid-name")[0].innerText = nameInput;
```

You should instead try something like:

```js
let arr = document.getElementsByClassName("kid-name");

for(let i=o; i<arr.length; i++) {
   arr[i].innerText = nameInput
}
```

Comment: It worked. Only thing I had to change was i=0, not i=o. Then it worked. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You're getting only the fist `kid-name` and not all of them. You need to cycle the result of the function `getElementsByClassName`

```
function nextForm() {
    var nameInput = document.getElementById("kidNameInput").value;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("kid-name");
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].innerText = nameInput;
    }
};
```